# Access denied error for S3 webhosting when S3 files are uploaded using lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have enabled S3 Webhosting for a S3 Bucket. To this bucket,iam pushing the web app files through lambda. When i hit S3 URL in the browser,iam getting 403 access denied exception whereas when i upload the web app files manually, iam able to access.

Bucket policy is updated as below

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<<bucket name>>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help with the suggestions.

Comment: Besides the policy, you need to disable `Block Public Access`, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html
Also, you may want to check if the ACLs allow public access.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi-Thanks for the suggestion.When i upload the files manually,i am able to access the website.So not sure if iam missing something when i push the files from Lambda

Comment: Figured out the rootcause.When the files are copied using Lambda,the target key had some extra characters.Hence files were not accessible.